# Корневая папка сайта на VPS

Tags: веб-программирование, vps

На VPS есть несколько папок, каждая- отдельный сайт, и соответственно- отдельный адрес.
Но все же, обращаясь к php файлу, находящемуся на уровень ниже, приходится задавать адрес, начиная не с папки, в котором сайт, а с корня VPS ( var/html/.. ).

Как исправить?

Есть еще странный момент, который пока не могу объяснить:
В папке есть js файлы, к которым обращаюсь по адресу вида /file.js. Если этой папке назначен адрес, файлы js функционируют, но если адрес не задавать, открывая сайт в папке по IP, сайт не может найти эти js файлы.
Объясните?

Comment: Почитайте про относительные и абсолютные пути. В php файле вы указываете абсолютный путь

Comment: Точно нельзя иначе? И что насчет второго вопроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос 1: подключайте через **DIR** 
Вопрос 2: смотрите в конфиги апача, а именно виртуальных хостов

Comment: Не подскажете еще, как смотреть нынешние хосты и соответствующие им папки? Httpd -S показывает только адреса, соответствующие папки не отображаются

Comment: @SonyaSeyrios, я обычно делаю  cd /etc/apache2/sistes-enabled; ls -la; После можно делать nano/cat любой из файлов. Это в случае debian/ubuntu. RPm /etc/httpd/sistes-enabled/

Comment: Спасибо! А без root?

Comment: @SonyaSeyrios без рута разве что посмотреть. `cat` Вам в помощь.